# Get index of a specific element in vector using %>% operator

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I want the index of an element in a vector x

```
x <- c("apple", "banana", "peach", "cherry")
```

With base R i would do that

```
which(x == "peach")
```

But as my x is at the end of a pipe I would like to get the index the magrittr way.

```
x %>% getIndex("peach")
```

My desired output is 3.

Comment: The strict magrittr way would be `x %>% equals("peach") %>% which`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to the left-hand side (lhs) of the pipe using the dot (`.`). There's two scenarios for this:

1. You want to use the lhs as an argument that is not in the first position. A common example is use of a `data` argument:

   ```
    mtcars %>% lm(mpg~cyl, data = .)
   ```

In this case, `margrittr` will not inject the lhs into the first argument, but only in the argument marked with `.`.

2. You want to include the lhs not as a single function argument, but rather as part of an expression. This is your case! In this case `magrittr` will still inject the lhs as the first argument as well. You can cancel that with the curly braces (`{`).

So you need to use `.` notation with `{` braces:

```
x %>% { which(. == "peach") }

[1] 3
```

Excluding the `{` would lead to trying to run the equivalent of `which(x, x == "peach")`, which yields an error.

Answer (score 3):

Or simply:

```
x %>% match(x = "peach")

# [1] 3
```

(Differs from `which()` in that it only gives you the **first** match):

```
y <- c("apple", "banana", "peach", "cherry", "peach")
y %>% `==`("peach") %>% which()
# [1] 3 5
y %>% match(x = "peach")
# [1] 3
```

Comment: To get several matches and keep the short notation, depending on the problem, we may use `x %>% grep("peach",.)`

Comment: @Moody that's not checking for equality.